# Why I got different signature when I perform RSA sign in C++ and Python?

Tags: python, c++, openssl, rsa, sign

I'm trying to create a RSA signature with sha1. The basic steps are:

1. Hash the source data with sha1 (to get the digest)
2. RSA sign with the digest and private key
3. Convert the signature to a hex string

So, the Python code is something like this:

```
pri_key = RSA.load_key(key_file);
digest = sha1_func(data).digest();
signature = pri_key.sign(digest, 'sha1')     ;
return binascii.hexlify(signature);
```

The source data is:

> s34caoguangshui@163.com1100

And here is the final result:

> 2034c9d2cacfdac1a69b737ab00d3fc42e8533b656f638c60ca503924706e49f017d2b29c8efe6903927c2b02fd24a5f50fef49ba137697983ece22761082b00ac433362b305023814e95278641ad8d8b3aa097f79bd392a325ee7182881b5e6a2d4e4d383c49a8842a3f6cdaee8deb33c257385aa2cf2946216cf09c6383145

I'm programming in C++ using OpenSSL library. I took the same steps I think, but got a different result. Actually I got only the first half of the result posted above:

> 2034c9d2cacfdac1a69b737ab00d3fc42e8533b656f638c60ca503924706e49f017d2b29c8efe6903927c2b02fd24a5f50fef49ba137697983ece22761082b

Where did the latter half go?

Here is my C++ code:

```
int rc = 1;
SHA_CTX sha_ctx = { 0 };
unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

rc = SHA1_Init(&sha_ctx);
if (1 != rc) {  }
rc = SHA1_Update(&sha_ctx, source_data, source_len);
if (1 != rc) {  }
rc = SHA1_Final(digest, &sha_ctx);
if (1 != rc) {  }

RSA* rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(private_key_file, NULL, NULL, NULL);

int sig_len = 0;
unsigned char* sig = malloc(RSA_size(rsa));

rc = RSA_sign(NID_sha1, digest, sizeof digest, sig, &sig_len, rsa);
if (1 != rc) {  }

return binToHex(sig);
```

In addition, I got the same digest from the first step.
I also tried the EVP APIs which is a more recommended way:

```
EVP_PKEY* private_key = PEM_read_PrivateKey(private_key_file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
EVP_MD_CTX evp_ctx;
EVP_SignInit(&evp_ctx, EVP_sha1());
EVP_SignUpdate(&evp_ctx, source_data, source_len);
EVP_SignFinal(&evp_ctx, sig, sig_len, private_key);
return binToHex(sig);
```

And I got only the first half too.

Comment: You probably didn't allocate enough space for the string.

Comment: binToHex may be the culprit. The short sig is cut off at a zero byte; C uses `\0` as the string terminator.

Comment: The buff sig is big enough. And @PM2Ring is right. Thanks a lot, both of  you.

Comment: Which duplicate would you like to use for this question: [different signature RSA site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=different+signature+RSA+site%3Astackoverflow.com). For OpenSSL signing, see [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) on the wiki. For OpenSSL and C++, see [C++ Programs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible inference from what you have provided is that the function bintohex is cutting off the signature as it encountered a "00" ('\0') which indicates the termination of string.The sig generated from your C++ code is converted to hex only till \0 isn't encountered.

What you can do is,try generating signatures for some other(test) message from both the python and c++ code,to narrow down the issue and ensure that bintohex is shortening the signature in this case,by observing whether you get same signature on other message body and if they are still not same see if c++ signature gets shortened at 00.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. There is no problem of making a signature. The real problem exist in translating string. Thank you very much!